# Vi copy and paste is not working

Tags: vi, conemu

When I open vi/vim in conemu I am unable to paste text from clipboard (mouse right button), and unable to copy file to clipboard (mark text).

However in git bash everything works fine.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse events are bypassed to vim. So you have to [enable](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html) mouse processing in vim itself.

However, ConEmu allows to [force Mark & Copy](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsMarkCopy.html) by pressing <kbd>LeftShift</kbd> or <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd> during mouse dragging with <kbd>LeftButton</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above solution:
Copy: "Left-Shift" and drag-mouse(left-key-pressed), and CTRL-C to copy.

Paste (in insert mode): Press "Left-Shift" and "Insert Key" together.

(to use above windows console properties may be needed to be updated for edit-options,
for quick-edit-mode, insert-mode, enable-ctrl-key-shortcuts,filter-clipboard).